# Reading, splitting, and displaying a multiline CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

All,

I'm trying to write a testbed program that will eventually allow me to take a CSV .txt file and put its contents into a SQLite database file. There are hundreds of lines to the .txt files I'm working with.

Here's what I have so far: a WPF form with three buttons-

Exit: self-explanatory

Load CSV file: pops up a Win32 Open File dialog box.

Current Directory Info: Finds the current directory the program is operating from, and displays it.

and a Text Block, that displays various information from the program's output- basically, whatever I want it to, things like exceptions, etc.

In order to read the text file, I implement the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace C_Sharp_SQLite_Testbed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private static string fileName;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document";
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";

            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                fileName = dlg.FileName;
                OutputConsole.Text = " ";
                OutputConsole.Text = fileName;

                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
                    {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var line = sr.ReadLine();
                            var lineWords = line.Split(',');
                            OutputConsole.Text = Convert.ToString(lineWords.Length);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OutputConsole.Text = " ";
                    OutputConsole.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            }
         }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
            lock (info)
            {
                OutputConsole.Text = String.Format("Directory info:    " + info.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a fairly simple setup, and the only method I'm having problems with is in `btnLoad_Click`. The `StreamReader` method receives the `fileName` variable from the dialog box as an argument. It successfully opens the file. While not at the end of the file stream, a line is read using `var line = sr.ReadLine();`. We then split the line up into an array using `var lineWords = line.Split(',');`. Afterwards, the length of the lineWords array is printed to the text block using `OutputConsole.Text = Convert.ToString(lienWords.Length);`. The problem is this: it would seem as if only one value is being read from the file, the reader stops at the first comma, and then ceases to read. The array value being printed is 1, and only one value is printed when I change `OutputConsole.Text = Convert.ToString(lineWords.Length)` to `OutputConsole.Text = Convert.ToString(lineWords[1]);`. Furthermore, it's not the correct value. So basically, I only have one space in the array, and it's not filled with the right value.

What do you guys suggest to change this? File reading in C# has never really been my forte.

EDIT: Here are the first two lines, as a sampler of what is in the file. It's Kinect output.

`Time,HLState,HLX,HLY,HLZ,KLState,KLX,KLY,KLZ,ALState,ALX,ALY,ALZ,FLState,FLX,FLY,FLZ,HRState,HRX,HRY,HRZ,KRState,KRX,KRY,KRZ,ARState,ARX,ARY,ARZ,FRState,FRX,FRY,FRZ,lknfx,lknvg,rknfx,rknvg`

Those are just headers.

Second line:
`700449555,2,-0.2912986,-0.1036692,1.472573,2,-0.2512482,-0.472762,1.416523,1,-0.2034467,-0.9132867,1.340637,1,-0.1271965,-0.9447169,1.280763,2,-0.197726,-0.09682589,1.596856,2,-0.1457276,-0.5412285,1.782268,2,-0.184881,-0.5280698,1.408923,2,-0.1630141,-0.537811,1.523656,178.867138094441,12.3859203137083,64.9231529324685,142.847159325228`

I believe the encoding is ANSI.

---

EDIT:

Here's the "new" block for the reading of lines. Works good so far, now, there's a need to split up things into a 2D array.

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);                        
    }

    int numberLines = lines.Length;
    OutputConsole.Text = " ";
    OutputConsole.Text += numberLines + " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberLines; i++)
    {
        OutputConsole.Text += lines[i] + "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)`

Comment: Or `string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName)`

Comment: And please, let us the contents of your file (or part of it) and its Encoding.

Comment: And avoid using `EndOfStream` or `Peek()`. Just check if `ReadLine() != null`

Comment: Have a look at [LINQ to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library)

Comment: Your overwriting all the values of your console text every line you read. So the only value you are seeing is the last.

Comment: Original post updated. I must ask, though, how will the program know to split the array by the commas from the original file? It tells me I can't use the `var lineWords = line.Split(',')` anymore on account of `System.Array` not containing a method for `Split`.

Comment: You wil have array of strings, which are lines in your file. You don't have to call `Split` on an array, rather than on each individual line

Comment: Hm... well, I need it to split both by line, and by the commas, if that makes sense. A two-dimensional array, perhaps?

Comment: If you want to store each cell's value of your csv in respective cell of a c# array, then yes, off course, you'll need a 2D array.

Comment: @Aaron McRuer, This solution works well. However, how would I just want to parse out specific keywords out of all the multiple line reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

First, define a class to hold the output of your file:

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyData() { }

    public MyData(string[] values)
    {
        Time = new DateTime(long.Parse(values[0]));
        HlState = int.Parse(values[1]);
        HLX = double.Parse(values[2]);
        HLY = double.Parse(values[3]);
        HLZ = double.Parse(values[4]);
    }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int HLState { get; set; }
    public double HLX { get; set; }
    public double HLY { get; set; }
    public double HLZ { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify you button event to populate a list of those objects

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document";
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            OutputConsole.Text = " ";
            OutputConsole.Text = fileName;

            var output = new List<MyData>();

            try
            {
                // First line skipped as we do not need headers.
                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1))
                {
                    output.Add(new MyData(line.Split(",")));
                }

                OutputConsole.Text = string.Format("{0} lines read.", output.Lenght);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                //let user know there was an error reading file
            }

            // Do something with output

        }
    }
```

Now you have a collection `output` of objects each with a strong typed access to your values, which should easily populate into a DB

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't clear. The `MyData` class should have a property for each of your CSV's "columns", named and typed appropriately. Also feel free to rename "MyData" to something more applicable to what you are doing.

Comment: I'll try and implement this. Will get back to you.

Comment: I've updated my post a tad so that `MyData` looks a little more like the data you posted in your CSV.

Comment: Noticed that on the `OutputConsole.Text = string.Format("{0} lines read.", output.Length)` line, `output` (what I assume is our list) does not have a member method `Length`.

Comment: One more thing. I'm trying to output the elements of the list, with `for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
{
    OutputConsole.Text += output[i] + "\n";
}`

but this only produces a list of "C_Sharp_SQLite_Testbed.MyData". It's not accessing the list, just the name of the class.

Comment: When the .Net has an object and trying to make it a string, by default it will call .ToString() on that object. Since we didn't override this, it outputs the type name by design; So if this is desired override ToString to your liking. However in this scenario it might make more since to bind the list to a grid and show that on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Your file reading code is a bit odd (it has some minor redudance) but I don't think it's the problem. Typically (following the msdn example) the while loop is written as such;

```
  string line;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) { ... }
```

Additionally as suggested in the comments you can just used `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);` and then loop over the lines with your split logic in the middle. I suggest removing `EndOfStream` from your code and using one of the other two approaches. I don't know that it will fix your problem, but that stands out as something that is not exactly normal.

Also, your output is bad because you're not appending to the text box, you're setting it's value. This means you're only going to see the length of the final line in the file. If you want to see the length of each line it needs to be `OutputConsole.Text += lineWords.Length + " ";` In case you weren't aware there is an implicit cast done there so there is no need for your explicit cast which just makes the code less readable.