# Using System.Data.SQLite my create table command does not succeed

Tags: c#, sqlite

After following some of the steps provided by the good guys in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840810/reading-splitting-and-displaying-a-multiline-csv-file-in-c-sharp), I was able to get a CSV file into a list and thus prepare it for writing to a SQLite database.

However, I have run into trouble once again. I create a database file, tell the SQLite engine (or whatever it's called) to create a table by the name provided by the user in a textbox. However, when it comes time to actually write to the table, it says no such table exists.

I have verified that the table does not exist by using a SQLite database browser. The .db file is created, but no further action takes place. Here's the code I have for all of this. The trouble areas are marked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace C_Sharp_SQLite_Testbed
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private static string fileName;
        private static string dataName;
        public static string[] lines; 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document";
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";

            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                //check for input in the table name textbox
                if(txtTableName.GetLineLength(0) == 0)
                {
                    string errorBoxText = "Please enter a name for the table.";
                    string caption = "Error";

                    MessageBox.Show(errorBoxText, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    return;
                }

                //create save dialog box for .db file
                Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog sdg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                sdg.FileName = "databaseName";
                sdg.DefaultExt = ".db";
                sdg.Filter = "SQLite3 Database File (.db)|*.db";
                Nullable<bool> saveResult = sdg.ShowDialog();
                if (saveResult == true)
                {
                    string fcs = string.Format("URI=file:{0}", dataName);

                    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(fcs))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
                        {
                            //cmd.CommandText = String.Format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}", txtTableName.Text);
                            //Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
                            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Console.WriteLine(txtTableName.Text);
                            //Table is SUPPOSED to be built here
                            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(@"CREATE TABLE {0} (Timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                            LeftHipState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            LeftHipX real,
                            LeftHipY REAL,
                            LeftHipZ REAL,
                            LeftKneeState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            LeftKneeX REAL,
                            LeftKneeY REAL,
                            LeftKneeZ REAL,
                            LeftAnkleState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            LeftAnkleX REAL,
                            LeftAnkleY REAL,
                            LeftAnkleZ REAL,
                            LeftFootState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            LeftFootX REAL,
                            LeftFootY REAL,
                            LeftFootZ REAL,
                            RightHipState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            RightHipX REAL,
                            RightHipY REAL,
                            RightHipZ REAL,
                            RightKneeState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            RightKneeX REAL,
                            RightKneeY REAL,
                            RightKneeZ REAL,
                            RightAnkleState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            RightAnkleX REAL,
                            RightAnkleY REAL,
                            RightAnkleZ REAL,
                            RightFootState INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            RightFootX REAL,
                            RightFootY REAL,
                            RightFootZ REAL,
                            LeftKneeFlexion REAL,
                            LeftKneeValgus REAL,
                            RightKneeFlexion REAL,
                            RightKneeValgus REAL)", txtTableName.Text);
                        Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            //for input file
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            OutputConsole.Text = " ";
            OutputConsole.Text = fileName;

            //for output file
            dataName = sdg.FileName;

            var output = new List<MyData>();

            try
            {
                //First line skipped as we do not need headers

                    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Skip(1))
                    {
                        output.Add(new MyData(line.Split(',')));

                    }
                    //int j = 0;
                    foreach (MyData outputLine in output)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}| {1} {2:N4} {3:N4} {4:N4}| {5} {6:N4} {7:N4} {8:N4}| {9} {10:N4} {11:N4} {12:N4}| {13} {14:N4} {15:N4} {16:N4}| {17} {18:N4} {19:N4} {20:N4}| {21} {22:N4} {23:N4} {24:N4}| {25} {26:N4} {27:N4} {28:N4}| {29} {30:N4} {31:N4} {32:N4}| {33:N2} {34:N2} {35:N2} {36:N2}\n", 
                            outputLine.Time, outputLine.HlState, outputLine.HLX, outputLine.HLY, outputLine.HLZ, outputLine.KlState, outputLine.KLX, outputLine.KLY, outputLine.KLZ, outputLine.AlState, outputLine.ALX, outputLine.ALY, outputLine.ALZ, outputLine.FlState, outputLine.FLX, outputLine.FLY, outputLine.FLZ, outputLine.HrState, outputLine.HRX, outputLine.HRY, outputLine.HRZ, outputLine.KrState, outputLine.KRX, outputLine.KRY, outputLine.KRZ, outputLine.ArState, outputLine.ARX, outputLine.ARY, outputLine.ARZ, outputLine.FrState, outputLine.FRX, outputLine.FRY, outputLine.FRZ, outputLine.LKFX, outputLine.LKVG, outputLine.RKFX, outputLine.RKVG);


                        //SQLite stuff--- TROUBLE HERE
                        string cs = string.Format("URI=file:{0}", dataName);

                        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
                        {
                            con.Open();

                            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
                            {
                            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO    {0}(Timestamp,LeftHipState,LeftHipX,LeftHipY,LeftHipZ,LeftKneeState,LeftKneeX,LeftKneeY,LeftKneeZ,LeftAnkleState,LeftAnkleX,LeftAnkleY,LeftAnkleZ,LeftFootState,LeftFootX,LeftFootY,LeftFootZ,RightHipState,RightHipX,RightHipY,RightHipZ,RightKneeState,RightKneeX,RightKneeY,RightKneeZ,RightAnkleState,RightAnkleX,RightAnkleY,RightAnkleZ,RightFootState,RightFootX,RightFootY,RightFootZ,LeftKneeFlexion,LeftKneeValgus,RightKneeFlexion,RightKneeValgus) VALUES({1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26},{27},{28},{29},{30},{31},{32},{33},{34},{35},{36},{37})",txtTableName.Text, outputLine.Time, outputLine.HlState, outputLine.HLX, outputLine.HLY, outputLine.HLZ, outputLine.KlState, outputLine.KLX, outputLine.KLY, outputLine.KLZ, outputLine.AlState, outputLine.ALX, outputLine.ALY, outputLine.ALZ, outputLine.FlState, outputLine.FLX, outputLine.FLY, outputLine.FLZ, outputLine.HrState, outputLine.HRX, outputLine.HRY, outputLine.HRZ, outputLine.KrState, outputLine.KRX, outputLine.KRY, outputLine.KRZ, outputLine.ArState, outputLine.ARX, outputLine.ARY, outputLine.ARZ, outputLine.FrState, outputLine.FRX, outputLine.FRY, outputLine.FRZ, outputLine.LKFX, outputLine.LKVG, outputLine.RKFX, outputLine.RKVG);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                        /*
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", output.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", i, j);*/
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OutputConsole.Text = " ";
                    OutputConsole.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            } 
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
            lock (info)
            {
                OutputConsole.Text = String.Format("Directory info:    " + info.FullName);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public MyData(string[] values)
        {
            Time = int.Parse(values[0]);
            HlState = int.Parse(values[1]);
            HLX = double.Parse(values[2]);
            HLY = double.Parse(values[3]);
            HLZ = double.Parse(values[4]);
            KlState = int.Parse(values[5]);
            KLX = double.Parse(values[6]);
            KLY = double.Parse(values[7]);
            KLZ = double.Parse(values[8]);
            AlState = int.Parse(values[9]);
            ALX = double.Parse(values[10]);
            ALY = double.Parse(values[11]);
            ALZ = double.Parse(values[12]);
            FlState = int.Parse(values[13]);
            FLX = double.Parse(values[14]);
            FLY = double.Parse(values[15]);
            FLZ = double.Parse(values[16]);
            HrState = int.Parse(values[17]);
            HRX = double.Parse(values[18]);
            HRY = double.Parse(values[19]);
            HRZ = double.Parse(values[20]);
            KrState = int.Parse(values[21]);
            KRX = double.Parse(values[22]);
            KRY = double.Parse(values[23]);
            KRZ = double.Parse(values[24]);
            ArState = int.Parse(values[25]);
            ARX = double.Parse(values[26]);
            ARY = double.Parse(values[27]);
            ARZ = double.Parse(values[28]);
            FrState = int.Parse(values[29]);
            FRX = double.Parse(values[30]);
            FRY = double.Parse(values[31]);
            FRZ = double.Parse(values[32]);
            LKFX = double.Parse(values[33]);
            LKVG = double.Parse(values[34]);
            RKFX = double.Parse(values[35]);
            RKVG = double.Parse(values[36]);
        }

        public int Time { get; set; }
        public int HlState { get; set; }
        public double HLX { get; set; }
        public double HLY { get; set; }
        public double HLZ { get; set; }
        public int KlState { get; set; }
        public double KLX { get; set; }
        public double KLY { get; set; }
        public double KLZ { get; set; }
        public int AlState { get; set; }
        public double ALX { get; set; }
        public double ALY { get; set; }
        public double ALZ { get; set; }
        public int FlState { get; set; }
        public double FLX { get; set; }
        public double FLY { get; set; }
        public double FLZ { get; set; }
        public int HrState { get; set; }
        public double HRX { get; set; }
        public double HRY { get; set; }
        public double HRZ { get; set; }
        public int KrState { get; set; }
        public double KRX { get; set; }
        public double KRY { get; set; }
        public double KRZ { get; set; }
        public int ArState { get; set; }
        public double ARX { get; set; }
        public double ARY { get; set; }
        public double ARZ { get; set; }
        public int FrState { get; set; }
        public double FRX { get; set; }
        public double FRY { get; set; }
        public double FRZ { get; set; }
        public double LKFX { get; set; }
        public double LKVG { get; set; }
        public double RKFX { get; set; }
        public double RKVG { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an empty ExecuteNonQuery before the command to build the table. It is just a leftover of the commented code or it is really there?

Comment: Steve, my mistake, that was a part of the commented code.

Comment: Just inserted them around each and every bit of SQLite logic. The error comes at line the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after the `INSERT` statements. Says that no such table is found.

Comment: I've been looking at parameters... what exactly is the mechanism that it acts through? I've done pg_prepare with Postgres before but nothing through System.Data.SQLite and C#.

Comment: `I have verified that the table does not exist by using a SQLite database browser`. If this indeed the case then it is premature to be focusing on the insert query.

Comment: Where is the code where you open MyDB.dat file or whatever you've called your SQLite database file? What does `dataName` contain?

Comment: The last time I used SQLite with C# was about 3 years ago. I opened the file like this: `_provider = "Data Source=" + HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "App_Data\\MY.DAT" + ";Version=3;Read Only=False;Pooling=False;";
        _conn.ConnectionString = _provider; _conn.Open()`

Comment: Prix, it may reveal errors if you used [this](http://pastebin.com/KnWM9ab9) dataset, which is just output from a Microsoft Kinect's lower body joints. Simple CSV; the "front-end" to the program I am building can be found in the link I provide in the question. Not sure why it worked for you and not for me.

Comment: There is a NaN in the final row, penultimate column in that Kinetics dataset.  But that doesn't explain why the table wasn't created.

Comment: I don't know if I mentioned this, but it chokes on line one.

Comment: Sounds good. Just in case, I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and the SQLite package (x86/64) from NuGet... when you search for it in the package manager, it should be the first one that comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'll try to implement it and get back to you on it (I'm "off" on Fridays).